# JavaScript Algorithm Insertion Sort slightly off

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Here is the link to my [JavaScript Insertion Sort Algorithm](http://codepen.io/ideaguy3d/pen/wodgZg/?editors=0012)

Quite simply, I just can't figure out why I can't get that pesky arr[0] to get sorted correctly. I've tried everything I know of. *sigh*

It's pretty close though.

Any idea's

```js
var aoo = [5,2,4,6,1,3];

function jInsertionSort(a) {
  for(var j=2; j<a.length; j++){
    //console.log(j);
    var key = a[j]; 
    var i = j - 1;
    while (i > 0 && a[i] > key) {
      a[i+1] = a[i]; 
      i = i-1; 
    }
    a[i+1]=key; 
  } 
  return a; 
}

var aooSorted = jInsertionSort(aoo);

console.log("jInsertionSort = ["+aooSorted+"]");
```

?

[JavaScript Insertion Sort Algorithm](http://codepen.io/ideaguy3d/pen/wodgZg/?editors=0012)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it, this works:

```js
var aoo = [5,2,4,6,1,3];

function jInsertionSort(a) {
    for(var j=1; j<a.length; j++){
        var key = a[j]; 
        var i = j;
        while (i > 0 && a[i-1] > key) {
            a[i] = a[i - 1];
            a[i - 1] = key;
            i = i-1; 
        }
    } 
    return a; 
}

var aooSorted = jInsertionSort(aoo);

console.log("jInsertionSort = ["+aooSorted+"]");
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer since it's shorter than mine and works well. I cannot speak for OP and I highly doubt he took his time to check I was from Mexico. Just chill I didn't even get that many points

Answer (score 0):

```js
var aoo = [5,2,4,6,1,3];

function jInsertionSort (a) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var k = a[i];
    for (var j = i; j > 0 && k < a[j - 1]; j--)
        a[j] = a[j - 1];
    a[j] = k;
  }
  return a;
}

var aooSorted = jInsertionSort(aoo);

console.log("jInsertionSort = ["+aooSorted+"]");
```